# Mail from Gmail users go to junk mail and they should not

Tags: email, spam-prevention, outlook-express, email-filter

I have my Outlook express junk mail filters set nearly as low as possible, i.e., only the most obvious junk mail goes there. Yet numerous legitimate e-mails sent from other people's gmail accounts end up there.

Gmail seems to be the only sender for which this happens.

Is there an explanation?

Comment: Is there any reason you need to use Outlook Express and not a more modern email client like Windows Live Mail or Thunderbird?

Answer (score 1):

Check your blocked senders list.  Go to

```
Tools

Options 

Preferences

Junk Email

Blocked Senders tab
```

I'm guessing gmail.com got put into there somehow.

Comment: JNK,  Thanks for the suggestion.  No, there are no entries in my blocked senders list.  I should mention that not all gmail ends up in the junk mail folder.  Just a very high percentage of real mail from those users with gmail accounts.

Comment: Your other option will be to add it to the allowed senders list, but that would mean potential spam from gmail.com accounts.  You can also individually allow those users.  I'm not sure why else it would be doing this, unless they all have something in common that sets off the filter (like no title, or no text in the body).